# can we use features which require runtime permission in services in android M?

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

Is it possible to use features which ask run time permissions from user in service. i have not worked much on service so i do not have any idea will can someone help .

As it will ask user to grant that permission like [image]

Comment: You need to provide at least one UI screen to request permission..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use features which ask run time permissions from user in service.

You can use APIs that *require* `dangerous` permissions in a service. However, you cannot request the permissions from the service -- you have to do that from an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by following code and it worked well for me without any errors till now

In the Activity where u start the service

```
if(GivenPermissions()) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this,ServiceClassName);
     startService(i);
}
```

and the method code is

```
 private boolean GivenPermissions() {
        int hasLocationPermission1 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int hasLocationPermission2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (hasLocationPermission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (hasLocationPermission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So if the permissions are granted only start the service.Hope this might help